# How can i monitor network activity with nodejs (puppeteer)

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, networking, puppeteer

I am building an application using Nodejs  and firefox-puppeteer and i am trying  to monitor network traffic so i can  read the headers and if the headers match my Regex get a message printed on my terminal.

I have tried the puppeteer: `page.setRequestInterception(value)`
but that will just stop the application the moment it finds one of header and the program will break

Any suggestion welcomed
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to enable request interception via [`page.setRequestInterception`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) to listen for network activity (you might want to checkout [`request.continue`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestcontinueoverrides) for more information on that topic).

To simply listen for network responses, you can listen on the `response` event. Here is some example code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const textRegex = /(javascript|html)/; // example regex

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    page.on('response', (response) => {
        const headers = response.headers();

        // example test: check if content-type contains javascript or html
        const contentType = headers['content-type'];
        if (textRegex.test(contentType)) {
            console.log(response.url());
        }
    });
    await page.goto(`...`);

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
})();
```

This example listens for responses and prints all URLs that contain the string `javascript` or `html` in their `Content-Type` header.